# Editing values by replacing them

Tags: c#

I want to replace my values in text box without deleting them, for example, I output in my text box time `"HH:mm:ss"`  and if I type in that textbox first number I would like to change `"H"` on it, and so on. How can i do that?

I don't ask code, just an advice.

Comment: You failed to tell us what you have tried and which technologies you're using.

Comment: Take a look at the [`MaskedTextbox`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/) control